# Multiple commands during docker run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I am new to docker and I created a docker image which runs a rails app. Now I want to run the app in background as a deamon, but it keeps on bailing out on me:

```
docker run -d -p 2000:2000 image_name "source ~/.bash_profile; cd src; rails s"
```

As you can see, my rails app is in the src directory.

I have also tried adding the rails path in the bashrc for the docker image, still it errors out as below:

Can somebody please correct me.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message ? You should use either the CMD http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd or the ENTRYPOINT http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#entrypoint in your Dockerfile to launch your rails application, have a look at for example this Dockerfile https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/michilu/timecard-rails/dockerfile/

Comment: As a workaround here is what I did:
docker run --name app -d -w /src -p 3000:3000 image_name /root/ruby/rails s
However, I will look into ENTRYPOINT and send an update.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your commands in something like `startup.sh`, then make it executable. Then simply call `docker run -d -p 2000:2000 image_name startup.sh`
or if you want to always run this command when the container is started, take a look at `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands.

Also keep in mind that to keep docker containers running, you need to keep a process active in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
docker run -d -p 2000:2000 image_name sh -c 'source ~/.bash_profile; cd src; rails s'
```

This is because docker doesn't support running multiple commands, while "sh -c " is one command.

Reference: http://timmurphy.org/2015/02/27/running-multiple-programs-in-a-docker-container-from-the-command-line/